# Re-using variables in docker-compose yml

Tags: docker, docker-compose

There are two articles describing using environment variable but my use case is different.

I have docker-compose file where I have 3-7 containers. Depends on situation.

```
version: '2'

services:
  db:
    image: example/db
  backend:
    image: example/server
  frontend:
    image: example/gui
```

Now, in above example all my images will use latest version, but I would like to control which version to deploy, therefore I want to define some variable version and use it in all my images, something like:

```
version: '2'

variable version=1.0.1

services:
  db:
    image: example/db:$version
  backend:
    image: example/server:$version
  frontend:
    image: example/gui:$version
```

Second example is wrong, but it shows my need what I want to achieve

Answer (score 6):

In the same directory as `docker-compose.yml` add an environment file named `.env`, then specify your environment variable.

[image]

After that, add variable into your `docker-compose.yml`

[image]

The `${..}` represents a variable in `.env`

Comment: I can't use external file. Version should inside docker-compose file

Comment: when running `docker-compose up ` it automatically check environment variable in `.env` so i'm not sure why you need to define a variable in `docker-compose.yml`. In deployment, it's practical to put variable into `.env` as it will help you to automatically sync with others CI/ CD such as TeamCity, Octopuc, CircleCI,...

Answer (score 5):

Docker-compose used Interpolation Syntax `${variable}` for variables and you missed that in your file.

```
version: '2'

services:
  db:
    image: example/db:${version}
  backend:
    image: example/server:${version}
  frontend:
    image: example/gui:${version}
```

So just pass the version to your `docker-compose` command

```
version=1.13-alpine docker-compose up
```

Comment: To pass version from command is not case,  i just need mentioned it in docker-compose file. Different file line env.properties is not vood as well

Comment: so you can export them as a system environment variable so you will then no need to pass to docker-compose, there is no other way arround